# Printing out a combination of list values in a nice neat way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

So, I have a program that takes 4 different lists and combines them into one list with every possible combination between all of the values of the lists.

```
import itertools

planet_mass = [3.29, 3.29, 3.29]
star_radius = [1.26, 1.02, 1.26]
teff = [5757, 5842, 5672]
semi_major = [1.046, 1.065, 1.031]
a = [planet_mass, star_radius, teff, semi_major]
sort_a = list(itertools.product(*a))

for i in sort_a:
    print("Planet's Mass = ", sort_a[i][i])
    print("Star's Radius = ", sort_a[i][i])
    print("Stellar Effective Temp = ", sort_a[i][i])
    print("Semi-Major Axis = ", sort_a[i][i])
```

How do I print out each combination in a nice neat way?

Comment: `sort_a[1]` returns you a tuple so just `sort_a[1][0]`. (Btw. `sort_a[1]` is a **second** entry. First one is `sort_a[0]`.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Such an easy solution! Yeah, I realized that after you used 0 for your demonstration :)

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I actually want to print out every combination in a nice neat way. I've updated my post. I get an error when I try to do it. Could you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `i` as an index? Is that supposed to be pseudocode?

Comment: @wjandrea Not sure. I was just trying to figure it out! I actually figured it out. I used a while loop

Comment: @Zachary Why a while-loop? A for-loop would be better suited for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iterable unpacking in the for-loop, giving each element of each tuple a nice name.

As well, `a` and `sort_a` are not necessary.

You could also add another blank line after each loop to improve readability.

For example:

```
...
p = itertools.product(planet_mass, star_radius, teff, semi_major)
for mass, radius, temp, axis in p:
    print("Planet's Mass =", mass)
    print("Star's Radius =", radius)
    print("Stellar Effective Temp =", temp)
    print("Semi-Major Axis =", axis)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pandas dataframe, which will allow you to do a lot more than just displaying the data nicely:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

planet_mass = [3.29, 3.29, 3.29]
star_radius = [1.26, 1.02, 1.26]
teff = [5757, 5842, 5672]
semi_major = [1.046, 1.065, 1.031]
a = [planet_mass, star_radius, teff, semi_major]
sort_a = list(itertools.product(*a))

df = pd.DataFrame(sort_a)
df.columns = ["planet mass", "star radius", "teff", "semi_major"]
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', len(sort_a)):
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
    planet mass  star radius  teff  semi_major
0          3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
1          3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
2          3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
3          3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
4          3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
5          3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
6          3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
7          3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
8          3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
9          3.29         1.02  5757       1.046
10         3.29         1.02  5757       1.065
11         3.29         1.02  5757       1.031
12         3.29         1.02  5842       1.046
13         3.29         1.02  5842       1.065
14         3.29         1.02  5842       1.031
15         3.29         1.02  5672       1.046
16         3.29         1.02  5672       1.065
17         3.29         1.02  5672       1.031
18         3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
19         3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
20         3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
21         3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
22         3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
23         3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
24         3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
25         3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
26         3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
27         3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
28         3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
29         3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
30         3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
31         3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
32         3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
33         3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
34         3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
35         3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
36         3.29         1.02  5757       1.046
37         3.29         1.02  5757       1.065
38         3.29         1.02  5757       1.031
39         3.29         1.02  5842       1.046
40         3.29         1.02  5842       1.065
41         3.29         1.02  5842       1.031
42         3.29         1.02  5672       1.046
43         3.29         1.02  5672       1.065
44         3.29         1.02  5672       1.031
45         3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
46         3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
47         3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
48         3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
49         3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
50         3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
51         3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
52         3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
53         3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
54         3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
55         3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
56         3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
57         3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
58         3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
59         3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
60         3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
61         3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
62         3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
63         3.29         1.02  5757       1.046
64         3.29         1.02  5757       1.065
65         3.29         1.02  5757       1.031
66         3.29         1.02  5842       1.046
67         3.29         1.02  5842       1.065
68         3.29         1.02  5842       1.031
69         3.29         1.02  5672       1.046
70         3.29         1.02  5672       1.065
71         3.29         1.02  5672       1.031
72         3.29         1.26  5757       1.046
73         3.29         1.26  5757       1.065
74         3.29         1.26  5757       1.031
75         3.29         1.26  5842       1.046
76         3.29         1.26  5842       1.065
77         3.29         1.26  5842       1.031
78         3.29         1.26  5672       1.046
79         3.29         1.26  5672       1.065
80         3.29         1.26  5672       1.031
```